# After upgrading WordPress, can't access admin interface

Tags: admin, updates

After performing a WordPress upgrade to 3.3.1, I can no longer access the administration interface. The website works fine, but when I click on Dashboard, I receive the following error:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function _wp_admin_html_begin() in **/home/a7938356/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php** on line **40**

... help! What can I do? I don't have a lot of content, so I could reinstall WordPress, but I'd like to know what went wrong and prevent it in the future.

Website: http://www.stephenwade.me/
Current version: 3.3.1
Not sure what version I upgraded from.
Site hosting: http://www.000webhost.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely was a bad upgrade. You should manually download the latest WP version and overwrite all directories except wp-content. Your wp-config.php file won't be overwritten. This should fix the issue.

Comment: After a bit more fussing with plugin and theme upgrades, waiting, then manually deleting the .maintenance file, I'm back in business. Thanks for the idea: I didn't know you could upgrade manually nor how to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is often a plugin conflict. Rename the plugins folder to something like plugins-off, then go to your admin if it works, visit the plugins page. it will uninstall all the plugins, then just rename the folder and re-activate them one by own. Otherwise Brian's answer might do the trick.